# What is the best estimate of a signal given multiple noisy realisations

Tags: denoising

I assume that the noise corrupting the sought-for signal is [Edit: Gaussian] white noise of zero mean and unknown variance. Is the optimal solution simply the mean over the realisations (the ensemble mean), or, we can have a better estimate, say, in terms of a smaller root-mean-square-error?

Edit: I found that my question have been asked [already](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/signal-recovery-from-multiple-noisy-sensors). Although the practical context is different, as in my case there is no concern that the different observations on different sensors could be correlated or that the corrupting process is slightly different. The answer to that question suggests that superposition, i.e., ensemble mean, is the best (“efficient"?) estimate. However, it occurs to me that it might not be the case, as a moving-window temporal average of the ensemble mean would yield an even smaller RMSE if the signal is sufficiently smooth. Unfortunately, there was no published reference given there. It would be great to find the answer in a textbook or paper, as it would surely clarify the conditions under which the result/theorem applies.

In any case, even if the moving average of the ensemble mean yields a better RMSE than the ensemble mean alone, I wonder if there is an even better estimate. Intuitively -- and it might be a common failure of intuition -- there might be value (information) in having the relaisations available "separately" as opposed to only their superposition, the ensemble mean. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The probability distribution and dynamics of the signal also matter.  As a for-instance, if the signal can be modeled as the output of a **known** system of ordinary differential equations driven by Gaussian noise, if the measurement can be modeled as corrupted by additive Gaussian noise, and if the optimization criteria is least-squares noise, then -- **and only then** -- the Kalman filter is optimal.  But if you don't know the model exactly, or if it's nonlinear, or if any of 100 other things are different, then some _other_ filter is optimal, or at least better.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is *efficient estimator*. That's the least-variance (== least RMS) estimator for a given amount of observation.

Whether or not that's the average depends on your noise distribution.

For example, consider the two noises:

1. continuous-valued uniformly distributed noise
2. Noise that *only* takes values $\in \{-\sigma, 0, \sigma\}$ with equal probability.

Both can have the same variance, both are zero mean. Both can be white. But while the average sounds like a good idea for the first one, for the second one you can get a 0 RMS estimator as soon as you've observed three different values by picking the middle one.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. I edited the question to clarify that the noise is normally distributed.

Comment: Then, the first paragraph still applies: when you look for "efficient estimator gaussian noise", you should find what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Marcus. Is it something that i can find in a textbook? Taking a moving average in addition seems to yield a better result if the signal is sufficiently smooth. I wonder how the result/theorem is formulated precisely.

Comment: Yes, every textbook on estimator theory. Look for efficient estimators.

Comment: Hi: A moving average has an equivalence to exponential smoothing when the relation, $\lambda = \frac{2}{n+1}$ holds so, as far as "textbook" material, you may want to look at exponential smoothing. It will be discussed mostly in time series type textbooks but some DSP texts may have it also ? I'm not sure about the latter.

Comment: Below is the best book I know of for exponential smoothing. It's also discussed a lot in other rexts but this text gives an unusual amount of weight to it compared to others.https://www.amazon.com/Smoothing-Forecasting-Prediction-Discrete-Time/dp/0138153086/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1QDDWH3R7GH24&keywords=brown+prediction%2C+smoothing&qid=1643374857&sprefix=brown+prediction%2C+smoothing%2Caps%2C56&sr=8-1

Comment: If you have two time-series, y1[] and y2[], each containing the clean constant time-series x[] with zero-mean AWGN of variance sig1 and sig2 all of length L and you do not care about time/real-time, then any scheme you choose to combine y1 and y2 could also be used to combine y1[1] and y1[2] and so on. I.e. you could view this as L independent measurements corrupted by noise of sig1, and L independent measurements corrupted by noise of sig2. If you do care about realtime or there is some innovation in x, perhaps you can define a length N < L where it is approximately?

Answer (score 1):

(sorry about tangential post)
I was interested in Marcus' example, but could not get it to add up:

```
L = 100;
x = randn(L,1);
sigma = 1;
num_ensemble = 3;
n = (randi([0 2], L, num_ensemble)-1)*sigma;
y = x + n;
x_hat = median(y, 2);
rms(x-x_hat)
ans =

    0.6708
```

Then I took the time to actually read what he wrote:

```
L = 100;
x = randn(L,1);
sigma = 1;
for el = 1:L
    y_tmp = [];
    while length(y_tmp) < 3
        new_draw = x(el) + (randi([0 2], 1)-1)*sigma;
        if all(new_draw ~= y_tmp)
            y_tmp = [y_tmp new_draw];
        end
    end
    x_hat(el) = median(y_tmp);
end
rms(x-x_hat)

ans =

 0
```